# Groovy's "in" operator for lists

Tags: groovy

```
char c = '@'

println (['.','+','@'].contains('.'))  
println ('@' in ['.','+','@'])   
println (c in ['.','+','@'])
```

The above is printing
true
true
false.
Why does the last statement print false?

Comment: Because `['.','+','@']` is an array of strings.

Comment: If you can't get... and want inline working code, use this... `groovy -e "char c = '@'; println (c in (['.','+','@'] as char []))"`